# Convention badge description is misleading

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, badges, convention-badge

The description for the [Convention badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) on the [Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) states:

> 10 posts with score of 2 on meta

This is misleading as some may think that one would need 10 posts, each **requiring** an **exact** score of 2.

However, this is not the case, as this badge is awarded if one has 10 posts each with a score of **at least** 2.

Even though it may be common sense, some would take the literal description, thinking that it's a difficult badge to achieve.

The description of badges should be clear and not require users to "figure out" the actual criteria.

---

In this [Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions), the description is:

> #### Convention
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Post at least 10 posts which each have a score of 2 or more on the related meta site

**Would it be better to change the description on the Badges page to:**

> 10 posts with score of 2 **or more** on meta

---

Furthermore, changing the description would make it consistent with other badges such as:

**Teacher**

> Answer a question with score of 1 **or more**

**Pundit**

> Leave 10 comments with score of 5 **or more**

**Nice Question**

> Question score of 10 **or more**

and many others ...

Comment: Requiring an *exact score of +2* wouldn't make much sense, though. The meaning of the sentence is quite clear if you use common sense.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Agreed, but it's a little misleading

Comment: It is indeed not consistent with e.g. Nice Answer which says "score of 10 or more".

Comment: Same for the "Quorum" badge. It may be common sense, but it only takes two words -"or more", to make it completely clear.

Comment: While this may not be the most pressing issue for SO to address, I agree completely that there's really no reason to accept this kind of imprecise description. Yes, almost everyone reading it can figure out what the actual rule is, but why should anyone have to "figure out" something that could just be expressed plainly?

Comment: But common sense is neither.

Answer (score 9):

> 10 posts with score of 2 ***or more*** on meta

Good catch!  And that's not all.  There are 5 ***or more*** other unstated points in the Convention Badge description:

1. All numbers are in decimal.
2. No sock puppets may be used acquire the score.
3. "On" does not mean physically on top of.
4. Posts need not include freehand red circles to qualify.
5. Jon Skeet is eligible.
6. ...

Comment: you forgot the most obvious one: "10 posts OR MORE".

Answer (score -20):

I think it is correct.

*Technically* if you have a post with 2 or more upvotes on a meta it *did* at some point have exactly two.

The rules do not say that the posts with exactly 2 have to happen at the same time, just that you have to have had them.

Comment: By that logic, a post that hits two before being downvoted should count. It did _at some point_ have exactly 2 score, it just has less now.

Comment: @Kendra Hmm that is true :-) So maybe had exactly 2 rep at some point (and still has at least 2 ;-P)

Comment: @Kendra I cannot downvote my own post :-(

Comment: @Neal but you can delete it

Comment: Where is the fun in that @BlakeYarbrough ? :-|