# Use the same phrase in all badge descriptions for minimum score

Tags: discussion, support, badges, help-center

When I am looking on the [badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) in the help center, I can see numerous (but similar) ways of describing the minimum bar for a post:

1. "Nice question": `Question score of 10 or more`
2. "Explainer": `...answer score > 0)`
3. "Reversal": `Provide an answer of +20 score to...`
4. "Sportmanship": `...answer of yours has a positive score`
5. "Disciplined": `...score of 3 or higher`

I saw this raised more than three years ago as part of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321036/convention-badge-description-is-misleading?rq=1), but it was never addressed by Stack Overflow (or by any the answers for that question).

First I thought that the best will be to use the "20+" (for 20 and above) as "1+" (for score greater than 0), but giving the case of Reversal (`-3-`) we may stick to "X or more".

Should we align the description? What is the best syntax for that?

Comment: I understand from the down-vote this post gets that it is not clear, no research or not useful - can you please comment here what can I do to improve it? is it salvageable?

Comment: I'm not seeing a good reason to align the scores, especially given that the score could be a question score, or an answer score, or both. It might be a combination too (Reversal being "Provide an answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score" -- which score should be aligned where?). Consistency in how they are spelled out would be nice.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I meant consistency in the syntax - Sure each badge has its own bar. Regarding the syntax - it can be the same for both answer and question - as in your example of the Reversal tag. How weird will it be if it said: "Provide an answer of score > 20 to a question of -5 score". As the consistency in the Reversal badge (+20 and -5) so should be one format for all badges

Comment: "Align" generally refers to horizontal or vertical alignment. Text on this site is left aligned, and inbox messages are top aligned. So when you talk about "Should we align the description?" It's not very clear what you mean. I think most people are thinking you mean make all of the score values line up on the page in some manner, which would lead to some awfully hard to read text. If that's not what you meant, perhaps you can [edit] your question to make it more clear what it is you meant.

Comment: Oh, for me it was obvious - thanks for the comment. Edited

Comment: Heh, this is a real mess, isn't it? A few more forms: "score of 3 or higher", "score of more than 10" (is that actually a minimum score of 11, or just a fencepost error?), "score of 2" (I assume the badge doesn't get revoked if the score reaches 3!), "zero score" (kind of acceptable as a special case).

Comment: @dWinder Actually downvotes and upvotes on meta, despite the tooltip, have zero meaning on meta sites, as it was explained thrice to me and which I've seen elsewhere. It's a double-standard I once brought up (ironically that was downvoted). Some people treat it the same as on main sites and some people use it for arbitrary opinion of whether they 'agree' with it or not, which doesn't apply to discussion questions. There is no assigned meaning on meta for discussions.

Comment: @person27 - I had the same and then post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387332/why-do-we-vote-on-meta-posts-measuring-community-feeling yesterday after this one :)

Comment: Perhaps it is intended to be more readable by avoiding repetition.

Answer (score 33):

Some stats:

```
22 badges use "X or more"
4 badges use "> 0"
1 badge uses "positive score" (only Sportsmanship)
1 badge uses "or higher" (only Disciplined)
1 badge uses "+X score" (only Reversal)
1 badge uses "more than X" (only Populist)¹
```

I think it would make the most sense to change the outliers to "X or more" (or "-X or less") as this is the most common usage.

It is also extremely unambiguous, whereas "1+" could mean

> greater than one, but excluding one

**OR**

> greater than or equal to one

This is not to mention the negative case where "-1-" to mean "negative one or less" is very confusing.

---

<sub>¹Revival and Necromancer use "more than X" when discussing quantity of days and Tenacious and Unsung Hero use it when discussing quantity of questions, but I excluded them as they are not discussing score and therefore aren't apples to apples.  The verbiage in those could certainly be changed to be more consistent as well.</sub>

Comment: I note that if Reversal is currently "Provide an answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score", that really means "Provide an answer with net score of +20 or more to a question with a score of -5 or less". (Managing a +20 score on a question off of MSO with -5 is quite a feat, but you wouldn't be prevented from getting the badge if the score was -6 or worse.)  There's also the issue that the badge would only be issued once for a given answer, so there is a triggering threshold (-5 or +20) which is understood.  But spelling all that out exactly complicates the wording (and isn't all needed).

Comment: Yeah, and Reversal has been retired anyway so I'm sure there's not a ton of motivation to clarify the text given it can't be earned anymore.  Lifejacket and Lifeboat specify "or more" and "or less", so they're sufficiently accurate and unambiguous

Comment: I'd forgotten that Reversal was made "unearnable".

Comment: 1+ means 1, 11, 111, ... You know Regex, don't you?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm disappointed about reversal. When I finally earned it it had been retired already.