# Why do we vote on meta posts? Measuring community feeling?

Tags: feature-request, voting, meta

I asked [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387284/use-the-same-phrase-on-all-badge-description-for-minimum-score) yesterday in Meta and got a few downvotes. I thought my post was valid, so I decided to follow [this answer's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264437) advise and ask people in a comment, but I didn't get any answers.

I do think my question clear, useful and I did my research - do notice the "downvote" button said on the hint:

> "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Then I research a little bit and discover that **[voting is different on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)** (I didn't know that till today...) :

> "voting indicates agreement or disagreement"

I was surprised to discover it, but it seems reasonable (for at least the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tags and in my option for all meta posts). This make sense to me - as I believe my question was well formatted, but people can disagree with the idea.

I found it confusing having one voting system measuring both the post quality **and** agreement to the content.

Should we change the tooltip on the upvote / downvote button on Meta? Should we add a separate button to Meta for agree / disagree?

The practical dilemma in my case is: I want to delete a non-quality question, but if the question is good, but the voting is for disagreement, I want to keep it. In this case I am not sure what to do (that why I needed separate mechanism for those two criterion).

Comment: Related: [Change tooltip for up/down vote button on feature requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353758/2675154)

Comment: @honk Glad to know! I will delete the "support" tag and the hint change from the question. But should we still consider another tool for agree/disagree on Meta post? (I think for the majority of them it is needed)

Comment: '*I found it confusing having 1 voting system measuring both the post quality and agreement to the content.*' - IMO, it's generally quite clear when something is being voted on because of low quality and (dis)agreement.

Comment: @Script47 - I tend to disagree - on my post, I didn't know what the downvote were for (and I got 3 of them in couple of minutes).
Even here, does this post is clear and useful and the downvote of disagreement? I am not sure - maybe I need to spend some more time on Meta to have this instinct...

Comment: @dWinder from my understanding/experience, it's disagreement.

Comment: This question in particular, is quite unclear. It had multiple tags (discussion, support, feature-tag, which already points to problems most of the time). The title of the question seems to be a POB discussion type question, but the gist of question seems to be a feature request for a new feature about a pretty well discussed artifact of voting on meta.

Comment: @yivi and now, after the edit - it is better? can you please point me on how the question can be improved?

Comment: My edits simply corrected superficial problems. The main problems remain. E.g. the title doesn't match the question. The FR doesn't seem well researched, since there exist many discussions regarding this (e.g. a search [similar to this](https://www.google.com/search?q=agree+disagree+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com) wouldn't be a terrible starting point). Also, usefulness and agreement are still subjective matters. So you could improve the question and still receive downvote because some users believe this is not useful per-se, or disagree with your proposal.

Comment: @yivi the link you add in your comment is exactly what I wanted. I cannot mark it a duplicate because it is not on meta - should I just delete this post?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't overthink voting on Meta.

No matter how much guidance you throw at it, a post will pick up all kind of votes.

Those votes cover the range you are already familiar with extended with agreement and disagreement votes and the inevitable *not again* and *funny title* votes

It is hardly possible to judge a question on its score alone. For sure do check if you posted anything unclear, off-topic, badly researched or otherwise not useful stuff when down votes poor in but if you're confident that it is all fine and no comments claim otherwise then consider that some down votes are in the extended category.

Once you get an proper answer it becomes much more clear in what direction your question is going and the different "camps" become eminent.

If anything, optimize a meta question so it can be answered. Don't optimize for a positive score. You'll be disappointed every single time.

Comment: Thanks. What is your option about this specific question? should I delete it as it unclear or keep it in spite that fact it is duplicate? (I cannot mark it as one as it is from different site). I believe non clear question should be remove - but how can non-experience user like me tell the different?

Comment: You can't delete it as it has a positive scoring answer. And unless we (or I) find a better duplicate I'm not going to delete my answer. So I guess the question is somewhat fine, it fits the general feeling nowadays that Meta means murder. Hopefully your question and my answer will be found in searches by future visitors that have the same kind of question you presented here. Just leave it and move on.

Comment: so if voting is useless on meta, why does it exist? Remove it.

Comment: I've never said voting is useless @person27, I've made an argument that its votes carry several meaning which makes that you need to apply care when you jump to conclusions. We still get Unclear meta posts that will never be useful to anyone. The down votes on those posts are valid and send the correct message to visitors of those posts.

Comment: I never said you said voting was useless. I've seen decent questions with high negative scores, so it seems pretty useless to me. Just a logical deduction.

Comment: @person27 there are enough decent questions that are not useful. Just a logical deduction.